# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' in ubuntu server

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

i've a problem in my Ubuntu server mysql configuration.

Firtsly, i tried to install phpmyadmin. In the installation, i've seen "Your password does not satistfy the current policy requeirements". Than i searched in stackoverflow and i couldn't find a problem, i tried to delete and reinstall mysql server via this page : https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/mysql-resetting-a-lost-mysql-root-password/ but now i've some problem ass :

```
root@ip-*-*-*-*:/var/www# mysql -u root -p
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Could you please help me? 
Thanks.

Comment: You can use sudo su cmd before using MySQL cmd

Comment: root@ip-*-*-*-*:/var/www# sudo su mysql
root@ip-*-*-*-*:/var/www# mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Comment: Most likely means the `mysqld` server process is not actually running. Also, arbitrarily using _sudo_ to run any command is absolutely terrible advice @RohitIUC, especially when the error never even indicated a permission issue.